# How can I design a navigator system for a table which contains interdependent rows?

Tags: php, mysql, database, data-structures

#### Scenario:

I'm trying to create a interviewer robot. The robot asks multiple questions from everyone and then gives him/her a result. Overall, that robot investigates a person by asking some questions and then approves or rejects him/her for being employ in a company. Something like this:

[image]

Image above is just a simplified of real questions. In reality there is almost 1000 questions which everyone has to answer almost 40 questions *(based on his/her previous answer and company's needed)*.

---

#### My Question:

I have a table which contains those questions. Something like this:

```
// questions
+----+----------------------------+
| id |         question           | 
+----+----------------------------+
| 1  | What's your gender?        |
| 2  | What is your height?       |
| 3  | What's your age?           |
| .  | .                          |
| .  | .                          |
| .  | .                          |
+----+----------------------------+
```

Ok well, how can I find next question for each person based on his previous answers? I mean what columns should I add to database to use them as a navigator?

Comment: You need to add a level column and check if user qualifies for the previous level  then you can increase the level and get the question..

Comment: Great. Sexist robots. Bring on the Donald.

Comment: I love the part with "Male? - Stature?" ... "Female? - age?"

Answer (score 0):

```
| Level | id  | question  | answer
----------------------------------
| 1     | 1   |Your age   | 18-50
| 2     | 2   |Your height| 150-175-190
| 3     | 3   | wight     | 60 -120
| 4     | 4   | skill     | skill set


get level 1
  Your age ? -- 
  chcek age in answer -- fails-> exit / pass-> level = level+1
level 2
  yor heght 
  check height in (150-175) -- pass = level = level + 2  
  check height in (175-190)-- pass = level = level+1
  fails - exit
next_level
```

Actually this question is  completely choice based  and can implement as per his/her own choice of methods to achieve the result .. One of approach can be like the above stated

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific please?

For example, let's suppose a man already answered 8 questions and the current question is "do you like pets?" If yes the next question will be "do you like coffee?" else (if not) the next question will be "are you married?"

now let's suppose that a girl already answered 5 a questions and the current question is "do you like pets?" 
Does the next potential questions will be the same than for the man??

So does the full path of answers determine the next question or does only the last precedent answer determine the next question??

Comment: I ask this because your diagram and your description are not coherent together! Say what are you really trying to achieve please